# "the type new View.OnClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.OnClick(View)

Tags: android

I'm going through a beginner tutorial for android dev and I don't understand this error.

The error is on the line  "callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {"

Yes I know the code is badly written and a bit confusing, I'll clean it up after its working.

I'm trying to add a button that opens the contacts list and allows you to call.
package com.example.contactpicker;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Contacts.Intents;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactPickerTester extends Activity {

    public static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_picker_tester);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View _view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri
                            .parse("content://contacts/"));
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            }
        });


        Button insertContactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        insertContactButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                insertContactWithIntent();
            }
        });
    }


    private void insertContactWithIntent() {
        //inserting a new contact using intents//
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivity(intent);



 Button callButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

 callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v){
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("content://contacts/"));
         startActivity(myIntent);
     }
 });
 }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT): {
            if (resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                String name = c
                        .getString(c
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_contact_textview);
                tv.setText(name);
            }
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your list of imports to the code you've included?

Comment: And can you also specify which onClick listener it's complaining about? You have two in your code.

Comment: Yes, the post has been edited .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very simple, it's because you have wrote OnClick with an upper case on the "O" and it's a lower case.

So you must replace the line

```
public void OnClick(View v){
```

by

```
public void onClick(View v){
```

Note the capitalization change.

Comment: And you have forgot the "@Override"

Comment: Well, this definitely fixed the original problem! But it has brought new problems to the first onClick . "It must override or implement a supertype method". As well as many syntax errors in that body of code

Comment: Can you post the new code because I have tested your class in my Android Studio and there is no problem.

Comment: the new code is in the edit - it is working for me now too after some sytnax change - the only thing that doesnt work is button 3! The callButton. When I press it nothing happens. Do you know why mate? Thank you.

Comment: Write a Log to see if it goes through.

Comment: Like that : Log.d("Test","I push the button");